# How to draw a smooth connections between segments and arcs?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I am trying to make the following path:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
 \usetkzobj{all}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
 %\tkzInit[xmin=-5.1, xmax=12.1, ymin=-5.5, ymax=5]
 %\tkzClip
 \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O, 3/4/C, -3/4/B, 0/-5/o}
 \tkzDefPointBy[homothety=center o ratio .75](B)\tkzGetPoint{b}
 \tkzDefPointBy[homothety=center o ratio .75](C)\tkzGetPoint{c}
 \tkzDrawArc[thick,color=black](O,B)(C)
 \tkzDrawSegments[thick](B,b b,c c,C)
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

The result is: 
[image]

If you compile this, you will see that the connections are not perfect. This is clipped part (this is the tip of the "cat's" left ear):

[image]

How to fix it. I feel there should be an easy way. Actually it exists in TixZ, but I don't know how to draw an arc centered at O from B to C (which tikz-euclid does provide). I would appreciate the answer on either question. Thanks to everyone beforehand.

Comment: I guess you need to join the paths into one before you draw them.  I know how I'd do this in Metapost...

Comment: A dirty trick: `line cap=round, line join=round`

Comment: Already tried. Doesn't help. It shows line ends with round caps, but doesn't connect them properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a *pure* TikZ solution (using `calc` and `let` to compute coordinates and angles):

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path
  (0,0) coordinate (O)
  (3,4) coordinate (C)
  (-3,4) coordinate (B)
  (0,-5) coordinate (o)
  ($(o)!.75!(B)$) coordinate (b)
  ($(o)!.75!(C)$) coordinate (c);

  \draw[line width=5mm] let
  \p1=(B), \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},
  \p2=(C), \n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)},
  \n3={veclen(\x1,\y1)}
  in (B) arc(\n1:\n2+360:\n3) -- (c) -- (b) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Paul. This works for me with one small correction. Instead of \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)}, I wrote \n1={atan2(\x1,\y1)}. Hoang-Ngan Nguyen solution also worked on my machine just after I switched the positions of \XB and \XC. Probably I am using the old manual (pgf_2.10-CVS.pdf), but it says "atan2(x ,y) \pgfmathatantwo{x }{y} Arctangent of y ÷ x in degrees." So x comes first, and it worked for me. Probably, they changed the order of x and y in the newer version, that you are the most likely using.  Anyway, thanks to everyone, this really helped.

Comment: @SergeyBelyaev Your version of TikZ (2.10) is very old and uses the old syntax of `atan2`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because they are two different curves. One way to solve this is to draw everything in `TikZ` as one curve.

**Update:** I change `\pgfmathparse ... \edef ...` to `\pgfmathsetmacro` and `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro` (unit is pt) as suggested by @cfr in the comment below.

[image]

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
 \usetkzobj{all}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
 %\tkzInit[xmin=-5.1, xmax=12.1, ymin=-5.5, ymax=5]
 %\tkzClip
 \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O, 3/4/C, -3/4/B, 0/-5/o}
 \tkzDefPointBy[homothety=center o ratio .75](B)\tkzGetPoint{b}
 \tkzDefPointBy[homothety=center o ratio .75](C)\tkzGetPoint{c}
 \coordinate (OB) at ($(B) - (O)$);  % get coordinate of B when origin is O
 \coordinate (OC) at ($(C) - (O)$);
 \path (OB); \pgfgetlastxy{\XB}{\YB}  % extract x,y-coordinates of B
 \path (OC); \pgfgetlastxy{\XC}{\YC}
% old code
% \pgfmathparse{atan2(\YB,\XB) - 360}   % compute the polar angle
% \edef\leftangle{\pgfmathresult}       % store result in \leftangle
% \pgfmathparse{atan2(\YC,\XC)}
% \edef\rightangle{\pgfmathresult}
% \pgfmathparse{veclen(\XB,\YB)}        % compute the radius
% \edef\radius{\pgfmathresult}

%% new code after @cfr's suggestion
\pgfmathsetmacro\leftangle{atan2(\YB,\XB) - 360}
\pgfmathsetmacro\rightangle{atan2(\YC,\XC)}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\radius{veclen(\XB,\YB)}
\clip ($(B) + (-1em,1em)$) rectangle ($(C|-c) + (1em,-1em)$);
\draw[thick,red] (B) arc[start angle=\leftangle,end
angle=\rightangle,radius=\radius] -- (c) -- (b) --cycle;
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: You might consider using `\pgfmathsetmacro` rather than `\pgfmathparse` followed by `\edef` :-).

Comment: Less typing, at least ;).